# Gaming on two external monitors on MacBook Air M1

Tags: macbook-pro, display, dock, games, apple-silicon

I'm looking for a docking station capable of connecting two 1080p external monitors (pref via hdmi). I've found that it cannot be done directly but it's possible through displaylink and I have also found that Dell D6000 would probably do it.

1. Now I'd like to know whether all monitors connected through the dock are emulated via display link or if one is directly connected to the m1 GPU and the rest is display link - and if this is the case does it matter which port you use to connect the monitor for it to be using mac gpu? Because I'd like to play games and I think that through display link it'd be much worse experience if any at all.
2. Unfortunately Dell D6000 is completely sold out on my area. Would you suggest any alternative that'd support two external monitors (pref hdmi) - and if it's not a standard - with possibility to connect one monitor directly to mac gpu and second via display link?

Required ports: 2x hdmi or DP, 3x USB, Ethernet, SD card

Thanks for help!

Comment: Unfortunately not. All the info mentioned is what I already know. My question is more about personal experience of ppl using the dock solution. I dunno how they have it implemented and I need to find out whether you can connect two monitors using one dock while one monitor would be using M1 GPU and the other one display link. Or if both are through display link. The reason for this is that I wanna use one monitor for GPU demanding operations such as gaming and from my understanding display link would be slowing it down a lot.

Comment: I've been able to find further info on D6000 and it only uses alt-mode when you have 3 monitors plugged in. Otherwise it's through display link. So it depends on docking station implementation and is probably impossible to find one suitable for my needs. So I guess I'll use one display link dock and one USB-c to hdmi adapter to solve this. Source https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?s=cac482f8869fae1f34d368e781eff7af&p=83836&postcount=6

Comment: When you say gaming is this go and chess or are you implying you have FPS and refresh rate & resolution requirements? Editing your requirements clearly in the question helps us help you. This might be a “no” use one screen or get a mini instead of an Air so you get two external displays type of an answer…

Comment: The closest thing I could think of would be to use one AirPlay display and one physical connection. My understanding from research is that displaylink displays work best with lower resolutions/refresh rates. However, realize that most AirPlay displays will not sustain high frame rates.