# Macbook M1 (2020 13.3) is it possible to connect 2 external monitors not through same dock?

Tags: display, dock, hdmi

Is it possible to connect 2 external monitors not through one docking station?
I have a Macbook Pro M1 - 2020 - 13.3, trying to connect 2 screens:

1. LG 29'' WIDESCREEN
2. Dell U2719D - via DisplayLink Manager

I have already bought a usb-c hub of baseus as indicated below, but it has one hdmi input that works well, I need to connect the other screen via displaylink, I saw all the good docking stations for connecting 2 monitors cost in the area of 200$-300$ , is there Possibility to simply connect directly to the macbook such an adapter hdmi -> usb-c? (As I mentioned below from Amazon) and it will work?
If not, what are my options right now? Because the usb-c hub is good enough for my needs, just need to connect the other screen, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The thing is they all need the Display Link capability. The answer will most likely be no, because these adaptors are not "just a cable".

Comment: If you're trying to follow the hack from your previous post, then you're probably going to have to get one of the docks they mention will work with it.

Comment: Your options are layed out in the page linked to from your [previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/436256/macbook-pro-m1-13-3-looking-for-support-docking-to-2-external-monitors). Not sure what you expect in terms of answers.

Comment: [You’re basically asking if you can daisy chain displays](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406864/does-the-2020-apple-m1-macbook-pro-support-2x-daisy-chained-thunderbolt-displays). No, you can’t on M1.

Answer (score 1):

No. Display Link needs USB-A to work with the hardware you listed. You need additional external hardware or [a different dock](https://www.dell.com/de-de/work/shop/dell-d6000-universal-dock/apd/452-bcyh/pc-zubeh%C3%B6r).

- https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/how-connect-two-or-more-external-displays-apple-silicon-m1-mac-3799794/

The above article [you referenced in your previous question is spot on](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/436256/5472) about how to use Displaylink to get around the native limitation of supporting a third display on M1 hardware. It lists two options for you to consider to purchase for the third display.

I don’t recommend this, the drivers and adapters and time lost usually are more costly than getting a single wide display, but everyone gets to choose what they spend on and some people love the journey and experience DisplayLink provides them.

Your Pro behaves no differently than [MacBook Air looking for two displays.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/424184/5472)

Comment: UBS-**A**, hmm?

Comment: Yeah, the hardware is not ideal @nohillside bad experience and dongle jungle.

Comment: Are you sure it‘s not USB-C?

Comment: No, see [chat] … of course part of the chain is USB-C but then A gets connected sequentially before HDMI / VGA / DisplayPort comes out of the dongle jungle.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding here, but I am sure that you can use e.g. a Dell Display Link docking station to connect an M1 machine to and use two external screens via DisplayLink.

Comment: I would love for you to edit my answer with  parts you know work @X_841

Comment: https://www.dell.com/de-de/work/shop/dell-d6000-universal-dock/apd/452-bcyh/pc-zubeh%C3%B6r does the job with DisplayLink installed AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, confused hardware with USB speed :-)

Comment: I have had this conversation with dozens of smart, tech savvy people @nohillside it’s so hard to be clear. Everyone wants it to just work and mostly it doesn’t, or doesn’t well even if you’re spending $300 or more on the “dock”.